# Why does my firebase app work on an emulator but not on a real device

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a widget where it takes a future (The firestore data) and returns one of the two things

1. A list of food items
2. an x widget if the data is null

it works well on an emulator, but when I run the app on a physical device, it shows the x widget and returns this error

```
W/Firestore(13218): (24.9.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=error in frame handler, cause=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getBuffer()Lokio/Buffer; in class Lokio/BufferedSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.BufferedSource' appears in /data/app/~~IV3MigGjUwbjRknPcqpntA==/com.ableflyerstudios.foodwasteproject-Dc_mhdBDcRAYfPttwKOwJw==/base.apk!classes7.dex)
W/Firestore(13218):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.data(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1146)
W/Firestore(13218):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.readData(Http2.java:236)
W/Firestore(13218):     at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.nextFrame(Http2.java:148)
W/Firestore(13218):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1105)
W/Firestore(13218):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(13218):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(13218):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/Firestore(13218): }
W/Firestore(13218): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

The internet connection is stable, data is still there, and the rules are set to `if true`

I tried adding these to the android's `main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

but it would still produce the same result

here's the widget:

```
class FoodList extends StatefulWidget {
  const FoodList({super.key});

  @override
  State<FoodList> createState() => _FoodListState();
}

class _FoodListState extends State<FoodList> {

  Future<List> getItems() async{
    List x = [];
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc("${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}").collection("Items").get().then((value){
      for (var element in value.docs) {
        x.add(element.data());
      }
    });
    return x;
  }

  int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
    to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
    return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/options");
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, weight: 40.sp),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfffaf1d2),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.w, vertical: 20.h),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text("Food List", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.sp),),
                  Icon(Icons.local_fire_department, size: 32.sp,)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getItems(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty? Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.w),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 748.h,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return ListTile(
                          tileColor: Colors.white,
                          onTap: (){},
                          title: Text(snapshot.data![index]["Name"]),
                          subtitle: Text("Category: ${snapshot.data![index]["Category"]} | ${snapshot.data![index]["NumType"]}: ${snapshot.data![index]["Num"]}"),
                          trailing: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text("Expires in"),
                              Text(
                                  "${daysBetween(DateTime.now(), snapshot.data![index]["Expiry"].toDate())} Days",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.sp
                                  ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ): Center(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    size: 64.sp,
                  ),
                );
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

help is much appreciated

Comment: If you read the error message carefully you will see the actual error message: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getBuffer()Lokio/Buffer; in class Lokio/BufferedSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.BufferedSource'`. To me this looks like a version conflict of the okio lib(s). See also https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at the link below sent by @Robert

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5197

I have finally fixed this issue, here's how you can fix this if you're facing a similar situation.

1. go to `android/app/build.gradle`
2. add the following right above the dependencies

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
        force 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.5'
    }
}
```